# Computational complexity of a custom sort loop

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, loops, big-o

I would like to know computational complexity of my custom loop, I know that double loop is basically O(m x n), but this is different because I remove elements on the fly. So, I would like to know how can I know what is O of this?

I have created a custom sorting loop for my custom logic, like this:

```
static IEnumerable<Book> OrderList(IList<Book> bookList, IEnumerable<int> orderedIds)
{
var orderedList = new List<Book>();

var iterations = 0;

foreach (var orderedId in orderedIds)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < bookList.Count; j++)
    {
        iterations++;
        if (bookList[j].Id != orderedId) continue;
        orderedList.Add(bookList[j]);
        bookList.Remove(bookList[j]);
        j--;
    }
}

orderedList.AddRange(bookList);

return orderedList;
}
```

So, I take the list of books and order them by Ids like orderedIds are ordered. Also, if id of book is not present in the list of orderedIds, that book is appended to the end of the list.
When the book is found I remove it from the list to have less iterations.

Let's say I have five books with ids going like {10000, 23, 44, 9, 1973} (other fields are not important for the scope of the question) and that is passed in the function, also, let's say orderedIds should be {44, 1973, 23, 9, 100, 500}.

Function works as intended. Also, I use var iteration to check number of passes. So I know this is not O(m x n) based simply on that variable being 16 in this case.
How can I write computational complexity in O for this function?

Comment: It depends on how many books share the same orderId.  If all the books match the first orderId then it will be O(m + n).  If none of the books match any of the orderIds then it will be O(m * n).  If on the average some fixed number of books L match each orderId then that will result in the time being reduced by some constant factor k that is related to L, i.e. `(1/k) * O(m * n)` --- which is still `O(m * n)`.

Comment: Yeah, those cases make sense, I was just wondering if I can have one big O for all of those, looks like that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I know this is not O(m x n) based simply on that variable being 16 in this case.

No, you actually don't, Big-O notation does not claim that number of operations will always be equal to the computed value of the function for some particular set of input sizes (or always bigger or always less), it provides estimation of how run time (i.e. "number of operations ") or space requirements grow as the input size grows (`bookList.Count()` and `orderedIds.Count()` in your case, let's call them `m` and `n`). One major thing which should be remembered when working with Big-O that the function is determined on assumption that the input size can grow infinitely so it allows to "simplify" the function by removing the constants and members with lower degrees. So in reality on some input sizes algorithm with worse Big-O complexity can be significantly faster.

Now let's look at your function, as other answers explain - it will be `O(n*m)` (actually it will be worse, but will cover that later) - yes, you are reducing the number of elements in `bookList` with every iteration, so let's calculate sum of sizes in pairs for iterations (i = 0, i = m), (i = 1, i = m-1) ..., so "weighted" size of every element in every pair will be m/2, so you have `n*m/2` iterations hence the `O(n*m)` because constants are omitted.

Actually your implementation is worse, while `orderedList.Add` can be considered `O(1)` via amortized analysis (worst case scenario is `O(n)` when list needs to be resized, also can be mitigated by creating the list of needed size from the start), but `Remove` in `bookList.Remove` is `O(n)` in average case (due to need to move all elements after the removed one), so currently you are `O(m^2 * n)`.

What can be done here - if you have relatively big number of books - consider using hash table approach via `Dictionary`. Something along this lines (NB - not tested!):

```cs
static IEnumerable<Book> OrderList(IList<Book> bookList, IEnumerable<int> orderedIds)
{
    var orderedList = new List<Book>(bookList.Count); // create list of needed size so it is not resized

    // O(m)
    var dictionary = bookList
        .GroupBy(b => b.Id)
        .ToDictionary(
            gr => gr.Key,
            gr => gr.FirstOrDefault()); // assuming your don't have duplicates in bookList, use ToList if you do
        
    foreach (var orderedId in orderedIds) // O(n)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(orderedId, out var book) && book is not null) // O(1) in average case
        {
            orderedList.Add(book);  // O(1)
            dictionary[orderedId] = null; // O(1) in average case
        }
    }

    orderedList.AddRange(dictionary.Values.Where(v => v is not null)); // O(m)

    return orderedList;
}
```

Which should give us `O(n+m)` in average case.

Though again, if your both collections have around 5 elements - you really should not care.

Comment: Nice! Will defo try this out now!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like insertion sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

So O(n²)

To understand Big-O. You need to realise that the expression is proportional.
You are removing values in a linier way. If you plot this, you get a triangle.
The area of a triangle is (base×height)/2. The area of a rectangle is base×height. Thus, the area of a triangle and a rectangle are proportional. Therefore, the big-O is not changed.

If n and m are similar, then O(n²) ≈ O(nm). So the same type of thing. In the same way that an oblong and a square are both rectangles. In either case, the triangularisation, does not change the big-O

Comment: I would argue it is not a simple insertion sort, the thing making it different is that it depends on two factors (num of books and num of ids => m & n), thus making it some sort of O(m*n).

Comment: I missed that detail. However, if n and m are similar, then O(n²) ≈ O(nm). So the same type of thing. In the same way that an oblong and a square are both rectangles. In either case, the triangularisation, does not change the big-O.

Comment: I see, I am pretty new to this, just started. Awesome answer, tnks.

Comment: I would argue that despite word "sort" being present in the title, this is not an actual sort, it can be reduced to one, if we map the `orderedIds` into indexes and use this mapping function as source of ordering comparisons for `Book.Id` . But we should not, because the task is actually achievable in `O(n+m)` in average case (at least I think so =).

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, where none of the `orderedIds` are present in `bookList`, the outer loop will run `m` times and the inner loop will run `n` times for each outer loop iteration. This results in a time complexity of O(m*n).

In the best case, if all the `orderedIds` are already present in `bookList`, the function would only need to iterate over the orderedIds once and have a time complexity of O(n).

The average-case time complexity could be somewhere between O(n) and O(m*n), depending on the distribution of `orderedIds` in `bookList`.

When we analyze the time complexity of an algorithm, we are interested in how the running time of the algorithm scales as the input size tends toward infinity. This helps us understand how the algorithm will perform on larger inputs and allows us to compare the performance of different algorithms for solving the same problem. However, in practice, it could be lower depending on the number of matches found, and the order of the elements in the input collections.

Also, note that removing an element from an `IList` causes the remaining elements to shift, so the overall time complexity of your function could be even **higher** in the worst-case scenario. When you consider the time complexity of an algorithm, it is worth keeping in mind how it is affected by the methods of your structures.

You can read about `Remove()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8#system-collections-generic-icollection-1-remove(-0)).

You could try to use `LinkedList` to avoid this this performance issue. If it's not the case - an another approach to do this is by swapping the current book with the last book in the list and then removing the last book from the list. This way, you avoid the need to shift the elements in the list after removing an item, and the time complexity of removing a book becomes O(1) on average.

In summary, the time complexity of your function is O(m*n) in the worst case, and the actual performance could be influenced by the number of matches and the order of elements in the input collections.

Comment: Even though I am talking about O(m*n) it is worth considering it as O(n^2), as ctrl-alt-delor mentioned. If you are interested in the topic of time complexity of algorithms, I can recommend the book Grokking Algorithms.

Comment: Nice. Tnks for the detailed answer. Will defo try swapping approach.

Comment: Just one thing, how do you think looping from the end would benefit? I think swapping approach is defo always faster.

Comment: _"or loop from the end of the list to avoid this this performance issue."_ -  how this will help? Book which should be removed is "randomly" placed in list, so it does not matter how you iterate it to find the element to remove. Or have I misunderstood this part of the answer?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Yes, the swap option should work fine, but looping from the end of the list doesn't help in any way. Thank you for pointing that out!